# Is there anyway for windows application to use SQLite database located in drive created by ActiveSync in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, desktop-application, activesync

I have a windows application and a handheld application. They are sharing their data with a SQLite database file (it is the only way because no access pint is exists for WiFi).

Each time the Windows application needs the handheld data, it should get mentioned file from handheld and after processing data it should copy it back.

Everything works fine but by increasing data, the file size will grow larger and copy time too. If the copy time could be removed from process time, the data transfer speed will greatly increase.

The problem is when I want to make connection string for `SQLiteConnection` because the drive name is a simple `/` and visual studio can't recognize it.
In the other hand my question is:

> Is there any way to get SQLite data in drive `/` with desktop application without copying file to local drive?

and my request is:

> If there is anyway can anyone show me sample code in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you copying the file back and forth now?

Comment: new OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI().CopyFileFromDevice(Constant.SqliteDBPath_PC, Constant.SqliteDBPath_Device, true);

It needs a dll named OpenNETCF.